# Análisis de datos fecha_hora

Tags: csv, datetime

Tengo una lista con datos en formato fecha_hora, con mediciones cada minuto, con organizados en columnas P1 y P2, quisiera poder hacer un análisis de la completitud de los datos por día y por mes, ya que se evidencia en los datos la presencia de NaN, por lo que necesito saber la cantidad de NaN que tengo en los datos de un día y de un mes, y al mismo tiempo poder graficar el % de faltantes para cada mes.

Comment: En que lenguaje estas trabajando?

Comment: Podrías da más detalles de su problema para poder ayudarte?